# Undefined Index using array_rand PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to re-create an array by choosing random elements of an existing array using array_rand().

However, when using the following code and spitting out the array, I am getting an undefined index error in reference to it.

The array is `$city_users_trimmed`.

PHP code:

```
$rand = array_rand($city_users_trimmed, 1);

$data = array($city_users_trimmed[$rand[0]]);
```

I know that $city_users_trimmed has at least 1 element in it, so there is no reason I see why this wouldn't be working.

I tested it by running:

```
$data = array($city_users_trimmed[0]);
```

which works, so there is at least one element in the $city_users_trimmed array.  Is there anything you see that is causing this issue?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

> **When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry**. Otherwise, an array of keys for the random entries is
>   returned.

So in $rand is your key, not in $rand[0]

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc

> mixed array_rand ( array $array [, int $num = 1 ] ) Picks one or more random entries out of an array, and returns the key (or keys) of the random entries.

as you asked 1 key,  $rand is an int

Answer (score 0):

```
    $city_users_trimmed = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,8,9,90,8,6,5,4,5,76,78,75,643,54,543,53,43,5345,34534,535);
    var_dump($city_users_trimmed);
    $rand = array_rand($city_users_trimmed, 1);
    var_dump($rand);
    $data = array($city_users_trimmed[$rand[0]]);
    var_dump($data);
```

this code will give you the  Notice Undefined index in line 5 because of "$data = array($city_users_trimmed[$rand[0]]);" 
you cant treat with an simple variable as an array.
so right code will be

```
 $city_users_trimmed = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,8,9,90,8,6,5,4,5,76,78,75,643,54,543,53,43,5345,34534,535);
    var_dump($city_users_trimmed);
    $rand = array_rand($city_users_trimmed, 1);
    var_dump($rand);
    $data = array($city_users_trimmed[$rand]);
    var_dump($data);
```